# No matching distribution found for django on Window 11

Tags: python-3.x, django, windows

I am new to windows, have been a Macbook user for years. I need to setup an existing project on Windows 11. I have installed python, pip, pipenv and pyenv.

I have activated a shell to run the following command:

```
pipenv install --dev
```

Result

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django
```

Seems pipenv can not find any of the distributions at all. Not just Django.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What version of python do you have installed in your computer?

Comment: You may want to look into using the Windows Subsystem for Linux (wsl2). Essentially gives you a Ubuntu instance on your windows machine. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-wsl2-on-windows-11-with-gui-support#1-overview It has made things a bit simpler for me (especially if your ide supports it - Pycharm Professional does for example).